# Smooth scroll script issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm using a smooth scroll script for a site I'm currently working on, and I've got a really annoying problem what I've experienced before with the same script. It works nice and smoothly  but when I click on one of the navigation points what should lead me to the div(or a) I'm trying to target, it shows me the targeting area for like 0.1 seconds, and then it starts to scroll. It doesn't happen everytime, but often enough to be annoying. How could I prevent this? Here is the script I'm talking about:

```
$(window).load(function(){
                $(".contactLink").click(function(){
                    if ($("#contactForm").is(":hidden")){
                        $("#contactForm").slideDown("slow");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#contactForm").slideUp("slow");
                    }
                });
            });
            function closeForm(){
                $("#messageSent").show("slow");
                setTimeout('$("#messageSent").hide();$("#contactForm").slideUp("slow")', 2000);
           }

$(window).load(function() {
  function filterPath(string) {
    return string
      .replace(/^\//,'')
      .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
      .replace(/\/$/,'');
  }
  $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
    if ( filterPath(location.pathname) == filterPath(this.pathname)
    && location.hostname == this.hostname
    && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
      var $targetId = $(this.hash), $targetAnchor = $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      var $target = $targetId.length ? $targetId : $targetAnchor.length ? $targetAnchor : true;
       if ($target) {
         var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 110;
         $(this).click(function() {
           $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1400);
           var d = document.createElement("div");
        d.style.height = "101%";
        d.style.overflow = "hidden";
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        window.scrollTo(0,scrollToM);
        setTimeout(function() {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
            }, 10);
           return false;
         });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please, don't use any smooth scroll scripts on your site, because it will surely conflict with any user browser addon that implements smooth scrolling. That. Is. Very. Bad. Practice.

Comment: Looks like removing the return false didn't solve the problem anyway. Okay, but what should I use then? (the problem doesn't occur in Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
 $(this).click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
```

Now it rolls fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
        }, 10);
       return false;
     });
```

move the `return false` out of the `setTimeOut`